# rules on instantiation of existential variables in coq

Tags: coq

I'm working through programming language foundations and am confused by this line:

"Existential variables cannot be
    instantiated with terms containing ordinary variables that did not
    exist at the time the existential variable was created. "

Why not? Could I have an example of this that exhibits unwanted behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an illustrative example:

```
(* An empty type *)
Inductive empty : Type := .

(* A proposition quantifying existentially over an empty type can only be false... *)
Lemma this_cannot_be_true : exists x : empty, (forall y : empty, x = y).
Proof.
  eexists.   (* I'm telling you there is such an x, just put an evar ?x for now. *)
  intros y.  (* Now we must prove a universal property, so we introduce a new variable... *)
  Fail instantiate (1 := y).  (* Oh look, y : empty, let's instantiate our evar with it! *)
  (* If this didn't fail, we would have the goal (y = y), which would be proved by reflexivity. Luckily, the previous tactic failed. *)
Abort.

(* To clear out any doubt that the above proposition is false. *)
Lemma empty_type_is_empty {P : empty -> Prop} : (exists x : empty, P x) -> False.
Proof.
  intros [[]].
Qed.
```

Comment: This is really just scoping, which is pretty common sense. It's just that it can be a bit hard to see when you're using tactics instead of just writing terms. After the `intros y`, the proof term looks like `this_cannot_be_true := ex_intro _ _ ?X (fun y => ?Goal)`. The `instantiate` is trying to set `X := y`, and a following `reflexivity` would leave you with `ex_intro _ _ y (fun y => eq_refl y)`. This is rejected because you're trying to use `y` outside of the context where it is bound/defined (under the `fun y`).

Comment: That's a fine explanation. I just wouldn't assume people who ask that question to be familiar with the proof terms that the tactics generate. It's "common sense" only for those with the right background.